# How to create user in openfire using restapi in nodeJs application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, openfire, node-rest-client

This is my function in NodeJs app which I am using to create user in openfire.

```js
var createUser = function(objToSave, callback) {
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: url.resolve(Config.APP_CONSTANTS.CHAT_SERVER.DOMAIN_NAME, '/plugins/restapi/v1/users'),
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
            'Authorization': Config.APP_CONSTANTS.CHAT_SERVER.SECRET_KEY,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: objToSave
    }
    request(options)
        .then(function(response) {
            callback(null, response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Deal with the error
            console.log(error);
            callback(error);
        });
};
```

the **objToSave** is a json object contains username and password.

```
{
  "Username": "gabbar",
  "Password": "gabbar@123"
}
```

when i run this function i am getting the following error..

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I configured my secret-key properly and domain name is *localhost://9090*, can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that problem was with **request-promise**. it was not properly sending data in the required format. so Instead of that now I am using different module **minimal-request-promise**. and It worked like charm for me. After using that, my code looks something like this.

```js
var requestPromise = require('minimal-request-promise');

var createUser = function(objToSave, callback) {
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': Config.APP_CONSTANTS.CHAT_SERVER.SECRET_KEY,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(objToSave)
    };
    requestPromise.post('http://localhost:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users', options)
        .then(function(response) {
            callback(null, response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Deal with the error
            console.log(options);
            console.log(error);
            callback(error);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the options you provided needs `JSON.stringify` object before send it

The modified options is as below

```
const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: url.resolve(Config.APP_CONSTANTS.CHAT_SERVER.DOMAIN_NAME, '/plugins/restapi/v1/users'),
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
            'Authorization': Config.APP_CONSTANTS.CHAT_SERVER.SECRET_KEY,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(objToSave)
  }
```

Comment: No, It's not working. @yue you. still getting the same error.

Comment: try change your json to `{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "p4ssword"
}` as the doc mentioned https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user

Comment: Still no progress, I changed into above format but got the same error.

Comment: really. Maybe you can use some code irrelevant toolkit like postman to test api endpoint availability first